# How to use FormData with ABP's built-in RestService?

Tags: c#, angular, typescript, form-data, abp

I want to upload file in my ABP based application.

My application service is created like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<ScheduleDto>> UploadAsync(IFormFile File)
```

Which generated REST API endpoint like this:

[image]

Which is fine.

Now when I generate proxy, it created client side proxy like this, which does not accept file as input, instead it created JSON for `IFormFile`:

```
upload = (File: IFormFile) =>
  this.restService.request<any, ScheduleDto[]>({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `/api/app/schedule/upload`,
  },
  { apiName: this.apiName });
```

Since this method was not useful, I decided to use REST service provided by ABP framework as it handles success and failure internally. I injected `RestService` to component:

```
constructor(private matchService: MatchService, private scheduleService: ScheduleService,private rest: RestService) {} //
```

Using that service, making call using `request` method and passing file as `FormData`, but nothing happens when I post file:

```
UploadSchedule(files) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', files[0], files[0].name);

  this.rest.request<FormData, ScheduleDto[]>({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `/api/app/schedule`,
    body: formData,
  });
}
```

I can upload file using Angular's HTTP service, so nothing wrong with API endpoint. Seems like ABP generated service only support JSON data and not `FormData`.

Answer (score 2):

You can upload files with built-in `RestService`. Your code is fine, the only problem is you didn't return the observable, and no one subscribes to it. Also, `{ apiName: this.apiName }` seems missing. In short, change the `UploadSchedule` method to the following and subscribe to it from where you call.

```js
UploadSchedule(files) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', files[0], files[0].name);

  return this.rest.request<FormData, ScheduleDto[]>({
    method: 'POST',
    url: `/api/app/schedule`,
    body: formData,
  },
  { apiName: this.apiName });
}
```