# ABP.IO & Angular - Upload a file thank to IRemoteStreamContent

Tags: angular, file-upload, abp

I am trying to write an Angular application with ABP Framework with a file upload. I think I have to use `IRemoteStreamContent` (https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Application-Services#working-with-streams).

I wrote an application service to receive the file

```
public class MyFileAppService : MyAppService
{
    public Task<Guid> UploadFile(IRemoteStreamContent file)
...
```

However, I am not really familiar with Angular and Typescript and don't know how to use it in my Angular front-end. I updated the proxy (`abp generate-proxy -t ng`) and got the interface `IRemoteStreamContent`. However, I don't have an implementation class, neither a method to set the content.

```
export interface IRemoteStreamContent {
  fileName?: string;
  contentType?: string;
  contentLength?: number;
}
```

Is there a documentation I did not found? An example would be perfect.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It's been a year since your question. I found the issue [Make generate-proxy support IRemoteStreamContent.
#8581](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/8581) as still be "Open" at the time of writing this.

Meanwhile, I can find another solution that can help you or others.

> **Note**: Our solution is to use `Controller` to generate static proxy. You might use `IApplicationService` as entry point instead, but I hope the setup below will get same result.

This scratch on backend stuff.

```
// Controller
[HttpPut("{id:Guid}/picture", Name = "UpdateCategoryPicture")]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateCategoryPictureAsync(
    [FromRoute] Guid id,
    [FromForm] [Required] CategoryPictureUpdateDto model)
{
    await _categoriesAppService.UpdatePictureAsync(id, model);
    return Ok();
}

// Dto model
public class CategoryPictureUpdateDto
{
    [FromForm(Name = "title")] public string Title { get; set; }
    [FromForm(Name = "count")] public int Count { get; set; }
    [FromForm(Name = "isValid")] public bool IsValid { get; set; }
    [FromForm(Name = "file")] public IRemoteStreamContent File { get; set; }
}

// Application Service
public async Task UpdatePictureAsync(Guid id, CategoryPictureUpdateDto model)
{
    var category = await _categoryRepository.GetAsync(id);
    var url = await  SavePictureAsync(id, model.File);
    category.PictureUrl = url;
    await _categoryRepository.UpdateAsync(category);
}
```

This scratch on Angular client

```js
onPictureChanged(file: File) {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append("model.file", file);
  formData.append("model.isValid", "true");
  formData.append("model.title", "demo");
  formData.append("model.count", "48");

  // this is workaround to pass property file as FormData. 
  // Even though `file` property is IRemoteStreamContent type.
  // That's why I pass model parameter as any (utilize weak type to bypass)
  const model = {
    file: formData
  };

  this.categoryService.updateCategoryPicture(this.editing.id, model as any).subscribe(_ => {
    this.selectedCategory = this.editing;
  });
}
```

This is how it looks when generate static proxies

```js
public class CategoryService { 
  apiName = 'Default';

  // ...
  updateCategoryPicture = (id: string, model: CategoryPictureUpdateDto, config?: Partial<Rest.Config>) =>
    this.restService.request<any, IActionResult>({
      method: 'PUT',
      url: `/api/register/categories/${id}/picture`,
      // !!!BUG: The client proxy always uses property IRemoteStreamContent 
      // to send body after generated. 
      // I DO NOT change anything on this file because it's automatically generated.
      body: model.file,
    },
    { apiName: this.apiName,...config });

  constructor(private restService: RestService) {}
}
```

Here is the result you can get

[image: Debugging result]

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround here : [How to use FormData with ABP's built-in RestService?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65090534/how-to-use-formdata-with-abps-built-in-restservice)

However, I think it should be corrected in the ABP proxy because we loose the practicity of it by doing the call manually.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).